# Cat_plot in r: Does it work with a poisson regression?

Tags: r, interaction, catplot

I am considering using cat_plot in r to visualize interactions between two categorical variables.

However, do any of you know wheter it work on a poisson regression model?

e.g.:

```
model <- glm(event ~ sex * year + offset(log(PY)), family = poisson(link = "log"), data = data1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(outcome = rpois(100, 6),
                 covar1 = as.factor(sample(1:4, 100, replace = TRUE)),
                 covar2 = as.factor(sample(LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace = TRUE)))
```

Example Model

```
model <- glm(outcome ~ covar1 * covar2, family = poisson(link = "log"), data = df)
```

Plot

```
interactions::cat_plot(model, pred = covar1, modx = covar2)
```

[image]